# How to download file with certain name, set in .NET Core controller method, using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js, .net-core, download

I have defined an endpoint which returns a file to my front-end project. The endpoint is shown below:

```
[HttpGet("{shipmentId:int}/pod")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetShipmentPodAsync([FromRoute] int shipmentId)
{
   try
   {
      var result = await QueryBus
                    .SendAsync<GetShipmentPodQuery, PodFile>(
                        new GetShipmentPodQuery
                        {
                           ShipmentId = shipmentId
                        });

      return File(result.Content, result.Type, result.FileName);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      // ToDo: Handle exception in proper way
      return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, e.Message);
   }
}
```

The following function is responsible for communication with mentioned endpoint:

```
  async getPodFile(shipmentId) {
    const resource = `shipment/${shipmentId}/pod`;
    await client.getFile(resource)
      .then((result) => {
        const fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([result.data]));
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = 'display: none';
        a.href = fileUrl;
        a.download = `test.pdf`;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileUrl);
        document.body.removeChild(a);
      });
  },
```

I would like to use file name returned from my API, but i have no idea how to access it after receiving a response (I've tried to log a response object, but found no field like "filename"). How to use name, taken from the server instead of the hard-coded one?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to SET file name in the API.

For example you can do that in "content-disposition" header.
This is one way to do it:

```
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
             Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
            };

            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = recordToDown.Name
            };
```

Check "content-disposition" header in your API response, it should have property called "filename"

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. It helped me a lot because, you have pointed out that i need to look for content-disposition header :) Still it was not the solution of my problem - the controller method is written correctly, but i could not see content-disposition header due to the cors policy. I had to change the cors configuration as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63360439/12108254

Comment: It doesn`t hurt to vote UP or to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the solution - CORS were blocking the header including the filename. I had to add WithExposedHeaders to my CORS configuration:

```
        private const string ContentDispositionHeaderName = "Content-Disposition";

        internal static IServiceCollection ConfigureResourceSharing(this IServiceCollection services,
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var originsContainer = configuration
                .GetSection(AllowedOriginsSectionName)
                .Get<ICollection<string>>();

            return services
                .AddCors(o =>
                {
                    o.AddPolicy(PolicyName,
                        b =>
                        {
                            foreach (var origin in originsContainer)
                            {
                                b.WithOrigins(origin)
                                    .WithExposedHeaders(ContentDispositionHeaderName)
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                                    .AllowCredentials();
                            }
                        });
                });
        }
```

Addition of this line, solves the problem and filename may be obtained from this header :)